# Impossible to reconnect with another Google account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I wanted to connect to a Stack Exchange site, but by mistake I chose my Google account from work.

I noticed it on the page that asks me to create my profile.

I clicked on <kbd>Cancel</kbd> to go back and use the right Google account.

Here I was redirected to the login page, I clicked on "Login with Google".

From here I am always redirected to the request to create a profile for the first Google address (the one of my work).

I tried several times, I finally created this account, and then I deleted it.

I went back to the connection page, I clicked on "connect with google", and I was again offered to create my account on the Gmail account of my work.

I created the account (here I got two messages in my inbox to say I'm welcome, one from the deleted account and one from the new one and no profile picture).

[image]

I would like to reconnect with my correct Google address, but I don't see a "logout" button and when I go to my profile in "settings/access/your logins" and "add more login", I am redirected to my profile page and nothing happens.

I'm a bit lost, and I don't want to merge my two accounts [as said here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). I just want to log out and log back in with the right Google account.

If ever my post is not in the right section, sorry, I will move it.

The behavior really makes me think of a bug at the time, but since I don't know I tagged it with "support".

When I go to another Stack Exchange site (like  https://opensource.stackexchange.com) if I click on "Google login" or "Using email and password" I'm always redirected to the creation account page with the wrong Google account.

Comment: You can't use two Google accounts for same session. Once you are logged in with one account (e.g. your work account) to any SE site, whenever you'll try to login to any other site, you'll be able to use only that account. To use a different account, use different browser or a new browser session/profile.

Comment: I do not want to log in with two accounts but with one, the right one. So the ux of the site doesn't allow anyone to login with a wrong account? Same for a simple logout ?

Comment: Change the app like if you are on chrome switch to edge or whatever you have.  Or login with the correct ID in google in incognito.

Comment: I test all that solution, if I don't come back it's because it worked ^^